# Assembly x86 switch-case confusion

Tags: assembly

In the function switch_case, I'm having problems looking at it when it implements a jump table vs the easier L1:, L2:, L3: etc

```
     080483ec <switch_case>:    
     80483ec:           push   %ebp
     80483ed:           mov    %esp,%ebp
     80483ef:           sub    $0x10,%esp  //create stack space
     80483f2:           mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax  //param x
     80483f5:           mov    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)  //x moved into -0x4(%ebp)
     80483f8:           mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax  //param n moved into %eax
     80483fb:           sub    $0x21,%eax   //subtract 21 from n
     80483fe:           cmp    $0x4,%eax    //compare 4 with n
     8048401:           ja     8048420 <switch_case+0x34> // jumping to 804820
     8048403:           mov    0x80484e0(,%eax,4),%eax
     804840a:           jmp    *%eax
     804840c:           subl   $0x2,-0x4(%ebp)
     8048410:           jmp    8048427 <switch_case+0x3b>
     8048412:           addl   $0x2,-0x4(%ebp)
     8048416:           jmp    8048427 <switch_case+0x3b>
     8048418:           shll   $0x3,-0x4(%ebp)
     804841c:           addl   $0x1,-0x4(%ebp)
     8048420:           movl   $0xa,-0x4(%ebp) // default starts here x=10
     8048427:           mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax // n=x
     804842a:           leave
     804842b:           ret
```

My question is :

How do I know which instructions fall under which case?

so far I understood (translated to C):

```
    int switch_case( int x, int n) 
    { 

    int result = x; 

    switch( n) { 

    case ():
        x-=21; //guessing. dont think so?
            break;
    case ():

            break;
    case ():

            break;
    case ():

            break;

    default:
    x=10;
n=x;

            break;

          }//end 

    return result; 

    }
```

I know one case is x+=2; another is x-=2; another might be x<<3;x++; , but I am totally lost in finding out where they go and what the comparison is

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by `I don't see the offsets in the address of the instruction` - the line marked with question marks jumps to 0x8048420 - an instruction clearly visible in your snippet.

Comment: Fixed- not sure why I missed that

Answer (score 0):

The `subtract 21` is hexadecimal to start with, so that's `subtract 33` in decimal. Also it happens before the jump table is used. The logic is:

```
unsigned tmp = n - 33;
if (tmp > 4) goto default;
goto table[tmp];
```

That means, `tmp` may be `0`..`3` inclusive which in turn means the range for `n` is `33`..`36`. As to where the code is, you need to look at the jump table. Starting at address `0x80484e0` you will have 4 pointers, for the 4 cases.